# How to specify CMakeLists.txt to compile every target per every cpp file?

Tags: c++, cmake, match, filenames, target

I've got a bunch of cpp files, each contains a main function. I just wish to compile all of them in the patter like:

```
add_executable(algorithm1 algorithm1.cpp)
add_executable(algorithm2 algorithm2.cpp)
...
add_executable(findFile findFile.cpp)
```

I hope there's simplier way to avoid very similar lines. I need sth like

```
add_executable(EXTRACT_FROM_FILENAME xxx.cpp)
```

one line for all.

My question: can we achieve to compile/link and get the executable which name is from the source file? I know Makefile has similar funtionality, what about CMake? So next time I add a new cpp file, I don't have to modify this CMakeLists.txt file, and it will automatically compile the new file to target executable, with corresponding filename.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

project(Troskyvs LANGUAGES CXX)

file(GLOB one_file_sources RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} "*.cpp")

foreach(file_path ${one_file_sources})
  get_filename_component(filename "${file_path}" NAME)
  add_executable("${filename}" "${file_path}")
  set_target_properties("${filename}" PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
    LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
endforeach()
```

Comment: It works, but I mean is there a way to write a function like this in top level CMakeLists.txt? Or else I've to write this foreach loop in every CMakeLists.txt inside sub folders, right?

Comment: Do you mean add targets for all files from subdirectories recursively?

Comment: Try [`file(GLOB_RECURSIVE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob-recurse). I am expect it is working, I am far from my PC, can't test the recursive glob.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work and avoid the many pitfalls of globbing in CMake.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(example)

function(MyProj_add_tool filename)
  cmake_path(GET filename STEM target)
  add_executable("${target}" "${filename}")
endfunction()

MyProj_add_tool(algorithm1.cpp)
MyProj_add_tool(algorithm2.cpp)

# ...

MyProj_add_tool(findFile.cpp)
```

See the documentation for `cmake_path` here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_path.html#get-stem

Comment: I tried this, but my Cmake doesn't support "cmake_path" command. I'm using Ubuntu20.04 and cmake version is 3.16, which should be the version issue.

Comment: @Troskyvs - you should upgrade the version; it's easy since Kitware provides an [apt repo](https://apt.kitware.com). But you can replace `cmake_path` with `get_filename_component` and lower the minimum version.